# sed command using as substitute in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to get help with followings:

when I ran the following command I get error msg - dont know what I am doing it wrong

command I am running:

```
 sed -i ''s/$OLD/$NEW/g'' file1
```

error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

My goal is to be able to substitute `$OLD` to `$NEW` and save the file at the same time. Any idea how I can resolve the issue?

Comment: what is the value of $OLD - you can try `echo $OLD` same for $NEW

Comment: OLD or NEW contains a `/` or some other char sed doesn't like. The right way to do this depends on what you are trying to do so post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: What's `$OLD` ? what's `$NEW`? what's the content of `file1`?

Comment: @EdMorton please review the original post, it has 2 single-quotes not double-quotes. I didn't change that, just formatted the code.

Comment: NP, I guess the problem is with the SO editor.

Comment: I am still struggling to fix the issue!!!!! when I run the below commands I get as follows:                                                                                              bash-4.2$ grep new file1 | awk -F '"' '{print $10}' --> I return my expected result with some extra blank space - Is there any way I can show my result without blank space - just want to get integer value 

It's shows as  - after blank space I get the my result

20150501 
but I just want to display result without empty space
--------------

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use a variable with sed you need to enclose it inside double-quotes (`"`) , what you have on your code is 2 single-quotes (`''`)

```
sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" file1
```

---

If you still have problems make sure `$NEW` and `$OLD` are set.

```
echo $NEW
echo $OLD
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable input. Yes, I did try with " " as well

read NEW
OLD=$(grep "VERSION" file1 | awk -F '"' '{print $10}')
sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" file1

bash-4.2$ echo $OLD $NEW
201504220 201504221

$OLD and $NEW works but I still get the below error - really dont know the reason.

bash-4.2$ echo $OLD $NEW
201504220 201504221

file1 is actually xml file


error>>
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Please update your question with any more details you may have. And please format your code.

Comment: Again, I appreciate for your help

Comment: You're welcome, just make sure I've the necessary and formatted code in order to help you...